# Difference between Response.Cookies and Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie"

Tags: cookies, asp-classic

In classic ASP, when I am setting a cookie using Response.Cookies("data1") = "value1" then
I am able to read this cookie using Request.Cookies("data1") on the same page

But when I am using the syntax Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "data2=value2" then
I am not able to read this cookie using Request.Cookies("data2") on the same page.

So What is the difference between these two syntaxes of setting cookie and if I want to read the cookie using the second syntax how sould the read statement look like

Comment: That is because `Response.AddHeader` adds the headers during the response  *(data back to the client)* whereas `Response.Cookies` pre builds the collection before the response is sent, then sets `set-cookie` HTTP header when sending the response, this means until the response is sent there is time to modify the cookie collection.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods set the HTTP header

```
set-cookie
```

but with a key difference.

`Response.Cookies` is a collection that is pre-built then when the response is ready to send, the HTTP header `set-cookie` is created. This means that for the life of the page where the `Cookie` collection is specified, the values are available to manipulate as much as you want.

`Response.AddHeader()` sets the HTTP header `set-cookie` when the response is sent back to the client, it has no association at all to `Response.Cookies()` and setting

```vb
Response.AddHeader("set-cookie", "...")
```

will not magically populate the `Response.Cookies` collection. The only way to populate the `Cookies` collection without using `Response.Cookies()` is to make a round trip to the server after `Response.AddHeader()` has been set.